# how to use functionality from existing aspx page in usercontrol?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am trying to use existing functionality which is embedded in a asp.net aspx page. So I have controls on this page and code behind for it. What is the best way to reuse this functionality in a new ascx control? Or do I just have to copy everyting into the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just take the controls you want to use from the aspx page and turn those into a control? Then you can use that control wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

To access the page parent just written this.Page in your control. But for access to these methods, you must apply an interface to the aspx page.